# Create Angular component that behaves like ng-container

Tags: angular, ng-container

How can an Angular component behave like `<ng-container>` in that only its content is found in the DOM finally. In particular, if itself is written with content, the content shall end up in the template's slots, e.g. Suppose the template basically is:

```
<my-toolbar>
  <ion-toolbar></ion-toolbar>
</my-toolbar>
```

and the HTML is like

```
<my-toolbar>
  <span>stuff</span>
</my-toolbar>
```

then the rendered DOM should be like

```
<ion-toolbar>
  <slot>#ref to span below<slot>
  <span>stuff</span>
</ion-toolbar>
```

i.e. the `<my-toolbar>` host element is gone. Is that at all possible?

Tried so far: Several similarly sounding questions have answers as to use an attribute selector like `[my-toolbar]` and then write `<ion-toolbar my-toolbar>` yet then angular complains that `ion-toolbar` matches more than one selector, I guess the default and `[my-toobar]`.

Comment: I guess this is not possible? I need this as-well because it breaks the html sometimes. I know that you can make a component be an element like TR for tables: selector: '[componentName-tr]' and then it behaves like a tr tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside `my-toolbar` component template, you should add `<ng-content></ng-content>`

`my-toolbar.component.html`

```
<ion-toolbar>
<ng-content></ng-content>
<div>static div</div>
</ion-toolbar>
```

Usage:

```
<my-toolbar>
<span>some text</span>
</my-toolbar>
```

Result:

```
<ion-toolbar>
<span>some text</span>
<div>static div</div>
</ion-toolbar>
```